# Android dialog box and buttons

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have already developed a dialog box in android and I am using two buttons. But I don't know how to call another XML layout when a button is clicked. Please help me.

Comment: Where do you want to use this layout? In a new Activity, the original Activity, the dialog? Please post your relevant code and any LogCat errors to help us understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is call an activity with an xml layout assigned to it.  Take a look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog and you'll want to put something like this in an onclick event.

```
Intent i = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, Traffic_DroidActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```